# What does "of the first/second/third/etc. tone" mean in Iberian keyboard music?

Tags: scales, terminology, modes, organ

For example, "Tiento de 5° tono" - The fifth tone? Mixolydian? I'm not sure about whether "tono" refers to a scale mode because the music is scattered with accidentals that don't seem to follow the alleged scale mode.

Iberian organ works aren't published with the key signatures I'm used to (in the title) as Bach's or Buxtehude's. The titles often indicate tone, which I cannot, for the life of me figure out, and works that are in the same tone have different key signatures. There is very little info in English on this, so is there someone who can "decrypt" this aspect of the music of Cabanilles, Correa de Araujo, et. al.?

Comment: This http://www.paulayickvintagebrass.com/misc%202/Papers/Historical%20Styles%20/Chant%20as%20a%20Compositional%20Element/articles/French%20Baroque%20Organ%20Music.pdf describes the French version of "church tones" in some detail. I expect the Spanish version is generally similar.

Answer (score 2):

As suspected by alephzero, the word "tono" (in Spanish) or "tom" (in Portuguese) refers in this context to the "church modes", i.e. the [Gregorian modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_mode) of the plainchant tradition.

In *The Evolution of Organ Music in the 17th Century: A Study of European Styles*, John R. Shannon describes *Musical Flowers for keyboard instrument and harp*, the chef d'ouvre of the Portuguese composer Manuel Rodriguez Coelho published in 1620, as "... a well-organized anthology containing the following: twenty-four *tentos*, three each of the eight church modes;[...]" (p.130).

The *tentos* in the collection are named in succession "First tento of the first tone", "Second tento of the first tone", etc up to "Third *tento* of the eight tone" (the scores are available on line [here](http://orgaos-portugal.net/partituras.htm)).

The eight tones would be the 4 authentic and 4 plagal Gregorian or church modes, but as the *French Baroque Organ Music and the Eight Church Tones* paper referenced by **alephzero** points out, "in many pieces the tonal structures or keys seem to bear little relationship to those of corresponding plainsong tones". For example, the practice of applying a G minor "key signature" to pieces in the second tone is present in Coelho's work:

[image: coelho]
("IV. First *tento* of the second tone")

As well as different keys (e.g. D major) for the seventh tone (although not adopted as a "key signature", the accidentals place the piece clearly in that tonality):

[image]
("XIX. First *tento* of the seventh tone")

So judging by the example of Coelho's work ("the first monument of 17th-century Iberian keyboard music" according to Shannon), there seems to be great consistency between Iberian practice and that described in the paper about French Baroque organ music.

Comment: I haven't read alphazero's reference yet, in full. But it seems like composers follow the tone in their works' titles for the most part. I see the C/C# and F/F# in XIX above which sort of throw me off. It almost seems like the tone indicated in the title is then somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: I would be cautious trying to force a description of these pieces in terms of modern "keys". I'm more familiar with early English keyboard music, but pieces often meander between what we would now describe as closely related keys, and treat all 12 notes of an unequal-temperament scale (e.g. quarter-comma meantone) with almost equal importance. You can see that in the Coelho example with the F and C naturals and sharps. Sharps tend to be used in ascending passages and naturals in descending, as in the modern melodic minor scale, but not restricted to the 6th and 7th degrees of one fixed "key".

Comment: Some composers, including Correa de Araujo, used the newer 12-tone system introduced in the middle of the 16th century with the invention of the Aeolian and Ionian modes.

Comment: Also the key signature is applied to the first example here _because it's in transposed Hypodorian._  The final is G, so you need the B-flat to have the (Hypo-)Dorian mode.

Answer (score 0):

> because the music is scattered with accidentals that don't seem to follow the alleged scale mode.

The idea that modal music cannot use chromatic alteration is a 20th-century idea that is anachronistic for Renaissance and baroque music.  In fact, the major/minor tonal system developed as a result of the application of chromatic alterations to modal music (but not before the invention of the Aeolian and Ionian modes in the middle of the 16th century, giving rise to a 12-tone system).

> works that are in the same tone have different key signatures

This is because the tones can be transposed, just as with modern major and minor keys.  In other words, mode (and tone) are analogous to key quality -- major or minor -- than to key tonality.  You aren't surprised, after all, when two pieces in minor have different key signatures.

To demonstrate this, we can look at some examples.  You have to be a little bit careful with this, because there were different numbering systems for the 12 tones.  Glarean kept the original eight tones and added the four new ones (Aeolian, Hypoaeolian, Ionian, and Hypoionian) as numbers nine through twelve.  Giuseppe Zarlino renumbered the 12 modes in ascending pitch order (of the final) from C to A, as the original eight had been numbered in ascending order from D to G.  So later mode numbering schemes were inconsistent.

But we know that Manuel Rodriguez Coelho, composer of the examples in the other answer, was using the 8-tone system, so let's consider those examples.  The first has a key signature of one flat.  It is in the second tone, which is Hypodorian, a mode that normally ends on D.  This piece has its final on G, a fourth above D, which is consistent with the one-flat key signature: in modern terms we might say it's in G Dorian, and we would expect a key signature of one flat for a piece in G Dorian.  (This transposition is also indicated in the title given in [the source print](https://imslp.org/wiki/Flores_de_musica_(Coelho%2C_Manuel_Rodrigues)) by the phrase "per bmol.")

The second example is in the seventh tone, which is Mixolydian.  In the source there is the additional adjective "naturale," so we should expect there to be no key signature and a final of G.  There is indeed no key signature, but the piece effectively begins in D minor.  Still, if you look at the *end* of the piece, you do in fact find the expected G major chord.

> For example, "Tiento de 5° tono" - The fifth tone? Mixolydian?

The fifth tone is Lydian.  The eight tones:

1. Dorian
2. Hypodorian
3. Phrygian
4. Hypophrygian
5. Lydian
6. Hypolydian
7. Mixolydian
8. Hypomixolydian

Rather than go over the many versions of the 12-tone numbering I'll just link to and quote [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music)#Western_Church):

> In 1547, the Swiss theorist Henricus Glareanus published the Dodecachordon, in which he solidified the concept of the church modes, and added four additional modes: the Aeolian (mode 9), Hypoaeolian (mode 10), Ionian (mode 11), and Hypoionian (mode 12). A little later in the century, the Italian Gioseffo Zarlino at first adopted Glarean's system in 1558, but later (1571 and 1573) revised the numbering and naming conventions in a manner he deemed more logical, resulting in the widespread promulgation of two conflicting systems.
>
> Zarlino's system reassigned the six pairs of authentic–plagal mode numbers to finals in the order of the natural hexachord, C–D–E–F–G–A, and transferred the Greek names as well, so that modes 1 through 8 now became C-authentic to F-plagal, and were now called by the names Dorian to Hypomixolydian. The pair of G modes were numbered 9 and 10 and were named Ionian and Hypoionian, while the pair of A modes retained both the numbers and names (11, Aeolian, and 12 Hypoaeolian) of Glarean's system. While Zarlino's system became popular in France, Italian composers preferred Glarean's scheme because it retained the traditional eight modes, while expanding them. Luzzasco Luzzaschi was an exception in Italy, in that he used Zarlino's new system.
>
> In the late-18th and 19th centuries, some chant reformers (notably the editors of the Mechlin, Pustet-Ratisbon (Regensburg), and Rheims-Cambrai Office-Books, collectively referred to as the Cecilian Movement) renumbered the modes once again, this time retaining the original eight mode numbers and Glareanus's modes 9 and 10, but assigning numbers 11 and 12 to the modes on the final B, which they named Locrian and Hypolocrian (even while rejecting their use in chant). The Ionian and Hypoionian modes (on C) become in this system modes 13 and 14.